# Maven project from SBT project convertor?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, auto-generate

Is there a way to create (generate) maven project from existing scala sbt project via some script, e.g. automatically?

Answer (score 6):

Execute [`make-pom`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/api/sbt/internal/librarymanagement/MakePom.html) from [sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt):

```
sbt make-pom
```

You'll find the pom in `target/scala-2.11/`